# How to get default contextmenu items by code?

Tags: jstree

I want to hide all items in contextmenu when client use jstree to pick up any item in front end.
So, my questions are:
(1) Is there a way could be called from back end to hide all contextmenu items?
(2) Is there a way coule be used to get all contextmenu items from back end?

Comment: The problem has been solved, here is my solution:

Comment: The problem has been solved, here is my solution:(1) when defining a jstree, do not set plugin items to plugins collection directyly, bind the plugins collection to a funtion A instead.(2)Defining the funtion A , it is used to decide how to fill plugins collection.

Comment: Here is the code, for your reference:                                                                    .jstree({  "plugins" : A                                   ()                 }) ;                                                          function A (){  if ( )            
                {return ["wholerow", "contextmenu", "dnd", "types","unique"];}
           else
               { return ["wholerow","types","unique"];}   }